# Merging two related projects to one executable? (c sharp)

Tags: c#, merge, console, project

I'm currently working on a solution with two different project. One project is a windows form (main project) and the other one is a console application. Currently I am running the console application from the main project with:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\console.exe");
```

When I debug, everything works fine as a wish. However, C sharp creates two different executables, one with the console and another with the main project. My question: is there a simple way to merge those two to only one executable? Note: I am a beginner, and I tried really hard to get this working :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To merge multiple assemblys into one you can use [Fody/Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/). It allows you to merge multiple assemblys(exe's) into 1 project(exe). In your main project you add it (can be done via nuget). Then just in weavers.xml (file that will be automaticly generated add these text:

```
<Costura>
    <IncludeAssemblies>
       MyProject.MyConsoleApp
    </IncludeAssemblies>
</Costura>
```

(it should be the same name as the reference, so add the console app to your windows form as reference,and remember don't add the .exe suffix)

PS: read the tutorial on the link I gave you.

Comment: Can I install Nuget with C sharp express 2010?

Comment: I am not sure however you can always manualy download Fody and Fody/Costura and then put the 2 dlls in your folder, and add them as reference manualy, then make weavers.xml manualy in the main dir.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a real beginner. In which folder do i need to put the dlls?

Comment: ok, now I have two projects in one solution. One project is a console application, which is called from the windows form application. Now I want to add these to one executable. I was told that it was possible with Fody/Costura. I downloaded it and added the IncludeAssemblies code to the xml file. However, if i go to the debug folder, ther are still the two executables seperately (apart from some new generated files) Does the executable save in another place or did i do something wrong?